# How to add enum in generic lists

Tags: c#

How can I add only one enum item in a generic list?

```
public List<T> PopuleList<T>() where T : struct
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ProcessorEnum))
    {
        list.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)) as IEnumerable<T>); // This work, but I need to add only one value.

        list.Add(ProcessorEnum.B2B); // <- I need like this, but this give-me a compile error.
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but when you are checking `typeof` inside a generic method you're doing something wrong. Either you shouldn't be using generics or there will be a better way

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` will already bring all the values then why do you need `ProcessorEnum.B2B`? Am missing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double cast like this:

```
list.Add((T)(object)ProcessorEnum.B2B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `List<ProcessorEnum>` before calling `Add`:

```
(list as List<ProcessorEnum>).Add(ProcessorEnum.B2B);
```

Comment: @Selman22 Any reason why it won't work? `T` is `ProcessorEnum` because you checked that within `if` statement, so you can cast `List<T>` to `List<ProcessorEnum>`, can't you?

Comment: you can't even cast T to ProcessorEnum how can you cast List<T> to List<ProcessorEnum> ?

Comment: Marc, I guess it will result in compiler error. but I believe you can cast it to non generic list though

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek but only we know the list type is List<ProcessorEnum>, the compiler doesn't

Answer (score 0):

As @Selman shows in his answer, you can cast it to `object` then to `T` but this involves "Boxing and UnBoxing". You can avoid boxing and unboxing using this

```
list.Add((ProcessorEnum.B2B as T?).Value);
```

Comment: While this doesn't use the IL `box` instruction, it is still creating a new object that wraps the enumeration, only to pull the enumeration back out of it, which is essentially what boxing is doing.  This isn't really any different at a conceptual level.

Comment: @Servy but all this happens in stack where allocation is dirt cheap unlike the heap.

Comment: Allocating heap objects that don't live through any collection cycles are *also* dirt cheap.  Allocating a heap object means moving up the heap pointer a fixed amount and zeroing the bits, the same cost as for the stack.  If the object doesn't survive it's first cycle, the cost of collecting it is nothing; it just doesn't get found and copied.  The costs are only there if it starts surviving GC cycles.  The odds of a collection in the middle of this operation are...very low.  Not enough to be worth attempting to optimize.  You'll struggle to even *measure* the difference between these options.

Comment: That sounds plausible. However, let's leave this answer as it is as an alternate solution. It will be worth people who are not aware of this :)

Comment: There is an approximately 0% chance that this technique will actually be a worthwhile optimization for anyone...ever.  There is an even lower chance that those couple of individuals will actually find this answer.  The change is just *that* small.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the list needs to be a list of `ProcessorEnum` values.  The method is not in fact generic because it cannot accept any type of list.  You should simply make the method non-generic:

```
public List<ProcessorEnum> PopuleList()
{
    return new List<ProcessorEnum>(){ProcessorEnum.B2B};
}
```